# Merging nested lists alternatively

Tags: python

Input is `[[159,159],[21,21]]`
and I need
output like `[[159,21],[159,21]]`

I have searched python solution and tried a lot still am not getting solution, please share me solution.

Comment: "tried a lot ": perhaps share your best efforts, and try and indicate where you got stuck.

Comment: Have you tried working with the `zip()` function?

Comment: This is a duplicate, there are 185 Q&A on [\[python\] zip nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+zip+nested+lists)

Answer (score 0):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will do just that:

```
lst = [[159, 159], [21, 21]]

lst2 = list(zip(*lst))
print(lst2)  # [(159, 21), (159, 21)]
```

if you need the nested elements to be lists as well:

```
lst2 = [list(item) for item in zip(*lst)]  # [[159, 21], [159, 21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

1. [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) the data together
2. convert the zipped tuple to list using [`map`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp)
3. convert the whole thing to be a list

**Code**

```
data = [[159,159],[21,21]]
print(list(map(list, zip(data[0],data[1]))))
```

**Output**

```
[[159,21],[159,21]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
in_lists = [[159,159], [21,21]]
out_lists = list(zip(*in_lists))
print(out_lists)
```

which outputs

```py
[(159, 21), (159, 21)]
```

The `*` in `zip(*in_lists)` will "unpack" the iterator `in_lists` and feed them to `zip` as separate arguments, which will be like `zip([159, 159], [21, 21])`. The `zip` function then combines the i-th element from all iterables into tuples, which results in `[(159, 21), (159, 21)]`.